# how to import webfonts in blogger from google drive?

Tags: blogs, blogger

How to import webfonts in blogger from google drive? Which is hosted in google drive. Is it possible to do?

When i'm trying to use it trows this error in console

Font from origin 'https://drive.google.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use web fonts to your blogger. But make sure the font file sharing status should be in "Public". As per your description the file may be in private. First change status to be public, then follow any one of the method..

```
1. <link href='http://Font-URL' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> - add this line before your header close.
```

or

2. Add this line to your css.

   @font-face
   {
   font-family: ??;
   src: url(http://Font-URL.ttf);
   }

Comment: how to i change my sharing status public

Comment: @ abhay9455: It may helps you.. https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494886?hl=en